# Can I make a Mac hard drive recognizable on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, hard-drive, hfs+

I want a Mac hard drive accessible from Ubuntu.

Is there any way to do that? For example using MacDrive I can read Mac hard drives on Windows. Is there a similar thing for Ubuntu?

Comment: It should work just fine. Linux has an [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Linux) file system (read-only, last I checked).

Comment: I read somewhere if write support on HFS+ filesystem is needed journaling must be disabled on mac osx first.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, [Linux can read HFS+ volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS+#Linux). It can also write to HFS+ volumes, but only if they're formatted *without* journaling.

To do this, in *Disk Utility*, go to the *Erase* tab of that specific drive and format it as follows:

[image]

Linux should be able to mount the volume without problems.

Comment: However that does mean that when running in OSX and you shut the machine down the next OSX start could take a long time as it needs to verify the disk

Comment: Does it? I mean, I wouldn't format the boot volume without journaling anyway, or write to it from Ubuntu – it depends on what the OP really wants to do.

Comment: i just need to copy some content from a mac hard drive to my ubuntu 11.10 system.. i don't need to do anything fancy to make it work is what you guys are saying right?

Comment: No, you'll be alright! @ari